# Maven cannot load dependency from another dependency in repository

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am new to Maven, I try to load tranquility using the following in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.druid</groupId>
  <artifactId>tranquility-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I get an error: Failure to find com.fasterxml.jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.4.6.

I tried to search in search.maven.org, and find out that, inside the io.druid tranquility-core module, the dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to search Jackson-module-scala_2.11 in the central repository, there's no 2.4.6 version there, there's only 2.4.5 and 2.5.0. See the following link: [http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.module%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jackson-module-scala_2.11%22](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.module%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jackson-module-scala_2.11%22)

So is there a way for me to build it successfully even the module in central repository (in this case the tranquility module) makes mistake in referencing another module?

Thanks.

Comment: You could be right, it might be dependent on a version you which wasn't released or failed to release.  I suggest you try another version. (The alternative is to include a newer version of the missing library and hope it's compatible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can exclude the dependency in the io.druid tranquility, and dependency it by yourself with the exist version like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.druid</groupId>
  <artifactId>tranquility-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```